# Searching for a function similar to combinations() or how could i create one, given some 'rules'

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

As we know `combinations('ABCD', 2)` gives `AB AC AD BC BD CD` as result.
Now what i need is a function that will lead to this result `AB BC CD DA`
*** and in case of in case of ('ABCD', 3) i need 'ABC' 'BCD' 'CDA' 'DAB'
So the rules you might say are:

1. not to 'jump' any characters like `AC BD` in the first paradigm
2. include the combination of last and first character `DA`
3. the ability to be scalable, having a long string and a relatively big n
4. *! also one of the combinations must connect the last character/s to the first character/s

I know that it could be done with some complex for loops but in case of really large strings wouldn't that be "too slow"?

Last think to mention is that i'm going to store these results as keys to a dictionary if that could be of any help.

Comment: `s = 'ABCDA'; zip(s, s[1:])`. Note that there is no point in being picky about memory since you want to use them as keys of a dictionary. If there's a problem with memory you'll get it using the `dict` anyways.

Comment: that's very elegant but what do i change to make it work for n=3 when for example i need triplets ABC BCD....

Comment: @fractal_7 What is the expected output for `('abcde', 3)` ?

Comment: thanks for mentioning! very important. in that case i need 'ABC' 'BCD' 'CDE' 'DEA'. but in case of ('abcd', 3) i need 'ABC' 'BCD' 'CDA' 'DAB'

Comment: I don't get it now the two test cases seem incoherent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def combinations(my_string, n):
    result = []
    for i in range(0,len(my_string)-n+1):
        result.append(my_string[i:i+n])
    result.append(my_string[-1]+my_string[0:n-1])
    return result
```

Scalable and as fast as the combinations method.

*UPDATE*:

IDK, if the above code suits you or this one does, please provide better test cases.

```
def combination(string, n):
    result = []

    for i in range(0,len(string)-n+1):
        result.append(string[i:i+n])

    for i in range(len(string)-n+1,len(string)):
        result.append( string[i:i+n] + string[0:n-len(string)+i] )

    return result
```

Comment: yes the code below seems to cover every rule even the fourth which i forgot to mention in the first place.  you may want to keep only the second block of code it's the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be too complex though:

```
>>> [s[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(s)-1)] + [s[-1] + s[0]]
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA']
```

which is equivalent to:

```
results = []
s = 'ABCD'
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    results.append(s[i:i + 2])
results.append(s[-1] + s[0])
```

Comment: that looks great but when i change 2 with 3 
[s[i:i + 3] for i in range(len(s)-1)] + [s[-1] + s[0]]
i get ['ABC', 'BCD', 'CD', 'DA'] do i need to also change something in range ?

Comment: @fractal_7 yes, you'd need to adapt the rest of the code accordingly so that you're picking up on strings of length 3. This involves produces one less value for `i` and modifying the last part `[s[-1] + s[0]]` as that will now only result in two characters.

Comment: sorry i didn't chose your answer but the other one seems to need less customization each time i change n. And i need to encapsulate the whole think into a for loop and increase n automatically. however if i find time i will try to modify the comprehension above.